# How to return error message in sql query if value does not exist in database

Tags: c#, sql

I have a sql database with values in it. I want to cross check it with a value I input, and if the value doesn't exists in the database, the program returns a custom error message. How do I go about doing it?

This is the code:

```
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
       if (dr != null)
       {
           if (dr.Read())
           {
               var student = new StudentParticulars
              {

                  StudentName = dr.GetString(1),
                  SClass = dr.GetString(2),
                  SNRIC = dr.GetString(3),
                  FixedAmount = dr.GetDouble(4),

              };
               studentList.Add(student);
           }
           return studentList;
       }

       else
       {
           if (dr == null)
           {
               var student = new StudentParticulars
               {
                   StudentName ="",
                   SClass = "",
                   SNRIC = "0",
               };
           }
           return studentList;
       }         
  }
```

Comment: fyi: `visual studio` is an IDE not a language, do you mean `C#` or `VB`?

Comment: C#, the program i'm using is visual studio

Comment: are you using any ORM? Entity Framework or Linq-SQL?

Comment: Your query shouldn't be returning an "error message" - it should return an empty resultset, and your *application* would then return an informative message to the user indicating that no records were found (or, if a severe enough condition, an error).

Comment: I'm not sure about that thing. I'm doing an sql query in a web service method in microsoft web service.

Comment: Not sure about what thing?

Comment: What would the if else statement be to return an informative message when it returns an empty resultset?

Comment: You should probably be throwing an exception, not returning an error message. This isn't C.

Comment: Bazz's query about ORM,Entity Framework or Linq-SQL.I'm not sure about all those things

Comment: If you aren't sure, you aren't using them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using plain ole, ADO.NET, you have a few options:

1. You can write a stored procedure with an output parameter. You can then get the output parameter value after executing the query and check it. Then throw an exception if the value isn't what you want. You probably only would want to do this if you had some sort of complex procedure you needed to run in the database.
2. You can simply get the value of a sql query like: `select some_value from some_table where some_condition = met`. Then get the value returned by the query and throw an exception if it isn't what you want. I am assuming you want something like: `select count(*) from table where column = value;`
3. You can check the number of rows in your dataset after executing a query. If it is empty, throw an exception.

   ```
   if(dataTable.DataRows.Count == 0)
     throw new CustomException("Data not found");
   else
   {
     //process your data
     return somethingMeaninful;
   }
   ```

   Or if this method is simply supposed to be evaluating whether or not a value exists,
   do something like this:

   ```
   if(dataTable.DataRows.Count == 0)
     return false;
   else
   {
     //process your data
     return true;
   }
   ```

   Or with a data reader

   ```
   int processedRows = 0;

   while(reader.Read())
   {
     //do something with the data.
     processedRows++;
   }

   if(processedRows == 0)
     throw new CustomException("The result set was empty");
   ```

   For simplicity, I did not add connection handling here, but you need to close the connection in a `finally` block, or use the connection in a `using` block.

Comment: I'm actually using sqldatareader to query sql.
It goes 


if(dr != null)
{
while(dr.read)
{
return sth;
}

Comment: then just maintain a counter in your read loop and throw the exception if the counter isn't incremented. I am updating my answer to show how to do this.

Comment: I'm having an error saying type or namespace CustomException could not be found

Comment: That's because you have to define it. Hence, the word custom. You need to define your own exception and throw it. For testing, you can just use "throw new Exception("Your message here")";

Comment: I think I'm missing a reference or assembly. The definition of the exception is (processedRows == 0) right? As for the throwing isn't it happening in that condition?

Comment: just replace my line: "throw new CustomException("The result set was empty");" with "throw new Exception("Your message here");" You aren't missing any references.

Comment: Okay, the error is solved but another pops up. My method says not all code paths returns a value

Comment: then return something or change the method signature.

Comment: I have already return the array if the datareader reads something but after adding the if(processedRows == 0), the problem shows up

Comment: your return statement should be the very last statement in this context.

Comment: I have edited my question to include the code. I still haven't been able to print an error message